# Searching for non-visible characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm troubleshooting some strangeness in output of my SQL Server when I want to get records that are not null or empty string:

```
SELECT myString 
FROM myTable 
WHERE myString IS NOT NULL OR myString != ''
```

In addition to records that obviously fit (string values returned to SSMS's grid) I'm seeing records where the grid cell is blank. When I select the cell and try to *copy* it, my clipboard manager (clipmate.com) complains that the data is invalid.

If I output the query to file instead of to grid and then inspect via **Hex char mode**, sure enough - there are characters I would not expect (much less want) to be in there.

Collation of my database collation value shows as: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

How would I go about eliminating any/all non-visible characters?

Comment: ADDENDUM: While implementing the suggested answers over the weekend, I was working from a different install of SSMS (2016 vs. 12.0.5203.0) In both cases, I was connected to an Azure SQL db so the data itself was always the same. Same database - same query but from the newer version of SSMS I could not produce any records that had the non-visible fields. If you've participated in this thread it would be really helpful if you could check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336328/different-resultsets-from-different-versions-of-ssms --- many many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

can try this, will remove any characters that are not printable.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RemoveNonPrintableChars]
    (
        @p_string  varchar(max)
    )
    RETURNS varchar(max)
    AS
    BEGIN
       declare @l_pos int = 1
       declare @l_str varchar(max) = ''
       while (@l_pos <= len(@p_string))
       begin

          if (ascii(substring(@p_string,@l_pos,1)) >=32)
          begin
             set @l_str=@l_str+substring(@p_string,@l_pos,1)
          end
          set @l_pos = @l_pos+1
       end
       return @l_str

    END

declare 
@l_str varchar(max) = 'andrew'--select char(7)
select dbo.[RemoveNonPrintableChars] (@l_str)
set @l_str = 'andrew'+char(7)-- add NP character
select dbo.[RemoveNonPrintableChars] (@l_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

If by chance you can't use a UDF.

You may notice that I don't just strip the control characters here, I replace them with a space so not to concatenate strings.

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeField varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Michael'+char(13)+char(10)+'LastName')

Select A.*
      ,B.Value
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
              Select Value = replace(replace((
                 Select ''+C
                  From (
                         Select N,C=case when ASCII(Substring(A.SomeField,N ,1))>31 then Substring(A.SomeField,N ,1) else '{--space--}' end
                          From ( Select Top (Len(A.SomeField)) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By Number) From master..spt_values ) N
                       ) C Order by N
                  For XML Path('') ) ,'{--space--}',' '),'  ',' ')
             ) B
```

Returns

```
SomeField   Value
Michael     Michael LastName
LastName
```

> **EDIT**

However, If you do want a UDF consider the following non-linear approach

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Control](@S varchar(max))
Returns varchar(max)
Begin
    ;with  cte1(N) As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(C) As (Select Top (32) Char(Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL))-1) From cte1 a,cte1 b)
    Select @S = Replace(@S,C,' ')
     From  cte2

    Return LTrim(RTrim(Replace(Replace(@S,'   ',' '),'  ',' ')))
End
--Select [dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Control]('Michael'+char(13)+char(10)+'LastName')  --Returns: Michael LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

I like John's answers better, and would probably modify them if you were looking to control whether or not to include certain control characters. This is the function I used in the past to clean up some strings.

```
create function dbo.fnCleanVarchar (
  @StringParameter varchar(max)
, @CleanStyle tinyint = 1
  ) returns varchar(max) as 
begin;
  if @StringParameter is null 
    return null;
  if @CleanStyle > 3 set @CleanStyle = 1;
  declare @StringReturn varchar(max);
  declare @StringLength int;
  declare @CharacterCode int;
  declare @CharacterCodePosition int;
  set @StringReturn = '';
  set @StringLength = len(@StringParameter);
  set @CharacterCodePosition = 1;

  while @CharacterCodePosition <= @StringLength
    begin
        set @CharacterCode = ascii(substring(@stringParameter , @CharacterCodePosition , 1))
        -- Removes Unprintable Characters 0-8,12,14-31 
        -- If Style = 1, Remove Unprintable Characters except Tab (9), New Line (10), Carraige Return (13)
        -- If Style = 2, Remove Unprintable Characters except character 9 (Tab)
        -- If Style = 3, Remove Unprintable Characters and character 9 (Tab)
        set @StringReturn = @StringReturn + case
          when @CharacterCode >31 
            then char(@CharacterCode)
          when @Style = 3 
            then ''
          when @Style = 2 and @CharacterCode = 9 
            then char(9)
          when @Style = 1 and @CharacterCode in ( 9 , 10 , 13 )
            then char(@CharacterCode)
          else ''
          end;
        set @CharacterCodePosition = @CharacterCodePosition + 1
    end;
  if len(@StringReturn) = 0 
    return null;
  return @StringReturn
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking for non-visible fields is directly related to find non-visible characters, so consider these two notes:

Note 1: [SQL Server will auto-trimming spaces](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/56876/60970) in clauses so `N'   ' = N''` is true, and any continues strings of **empty** characters;
Empty characters are a character that is equal to `N''`.

Note 2: There are 65536 Unicode characters, you can view them with a query like this:

```
WITH CTE(i, c) AS (
    SELECT 0, NCHAR(0) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS --I add COLLATE to express your collation but I think it is optional
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i+1, NCHAR(i+1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    FROM CTE
    WHERE i < 65535
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
OPTION ( MaxRecursion 0 );
```

Some of those are **not visible** and **empty** like `NCHAR(0), NCHAR(12288), ...`,
Some of those are **not visible** and **not empty** like `NCHAR(1), ...`,
Some of those are **visible** and **empty** like `NCHAR(502), ...` !!!!.

> So if your field is a `nvarchar` string, you will have a big problem to filter **not visible** characters, and for `varchar` strings you have a problem but more little than that.

Side note: You can use `COALESCE(myString, '') != ''` instead of yours ;).

---

**SUMMARY :**
For a little pin don't create a hammer machine!.
When this behaviors are not so important for you and your project don't try to change or handle or create your own equal string function ;).

---

A sample function to check if a string is visible(returns 1) or not(returns 0) can be like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsVisible ( @string varchar(max) )
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pString varchar(max) = @string;

    WITH InvisibleChars AS (
        SELECT c COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS c
        FROM (VALUES (CHAR(0)),  (CHAR(1)),  (CHAR(9)),  (CHAR(10)), 
                     (CHAR(11)), (CHAR(12)), (CHAR(13)), (CHAR(28)), 
                     (CHAR(29)), (CHAR(30)), (CHAR(31)), (CHAR(32)), 
                     (CHAR(160)) -- Above characters are non-visibles
             )  t(c)
     )
    SELECT @pString = REPLACE(@pString, c, '')
    FROM InvisibleChars;

    RETURN CASE WHEN @pString = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
END
GO
```